# Python/Keras - Saving model weights after every N batches

Tags: keras

I'm new to Python and Keras, and I have successfully built a neural network that saves weight files after every Epoch. However, I want more granularity (I'm visualizing layer weight distributions in time series) and would like to save the weights after every N batches, rather than every epoch.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 15):

You can create your own callback (https://keras.io/callbacks/). Something like:

```py
from keras.callbacks import Callback

class WeightsSaver(Callback):
    def __init__(self, N):
        self.N = N
        self.batch = 0

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        if self.batch % self.N == 0:
            name = 'weights%08d.h5' % self.batch
            self.model.save_weights(name)
        self.batch += 1
```

I use `self.batch` instead of the `batch` argument provided because the later restarts at 0 at each epoch.

Then add it to your fit call. For example, to save weights every 5 batches:

```py
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, callbacks=[WeightsSaver(5)])
```

Comment: RuntimeWarning: Method (on_train_batch_end) is slow compared to the batch update (0.832980). Check your callbacks. My N value is 2500

Answer (score -1):

As stated by grovina you can create your own callback.
https://keras.io/callbacks/
Look at the source of 'callbacks' here : https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/callbacks.py#L148

Under Callback class, there are numerous functions for your desired requirement. In your case, if you want to save models every N epochs then define the function 'on_epoch_end'.

Sample Code

```
class WeightsSaver(Callback):
  def __init__(self, N):
    self.N = N
    self.epoch = 0

  def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
    if self.epoch % self.N == 0:
        name = ('weights%04d.hdf5') % self.epoch
        self.model.save_weights(name)
    self.epoch += 1

callbacks_list = [WeightsSaver(10)] #save every 10 models
model.fit(train_X,train_Y,epochs=n_epochs,batch_size=batch_size, callbacks=callbacks_list )
```

Comment: The question is how to save the model weights after every n batches, not epochs.