# save model weights at the end of every N epochs

Tags: python, tensorflow, callback, keras

I'm training a NN and would like to save the model weights every N epochs for a prediction phase. I propose this draft code, it's inspired by @grovina 's response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44058144/1545917). Could you, please, make suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

```
from keras.callbacks import Callback

class WeightsSaver(Callback):
    def __init__(self, model, N):
        self.model = model
        self.N = N
        self.epoch = 0

    def on_batch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        if self.epoch % self.N == 0:
            name = 'weights%08d.h5' % self.epoch
            self.model.save_weights(name)
        self.epoch += 1
```

Then add it to the fit call: to save weights every 5 epochs:

```
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, callbacks=[WeightsSaver(model, 5)])
```

Comment: Thanks @Ghilas_BELHADJ :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You shouldn't need to pass a model for the callback. It already has access to the model via it's super. So remove `__init__(..., model, ...)` argument and `self.model = model`. You should be able to access the current model via `self.model` regardless. You are also saving it on every batch end, which is not what you want, you probably want it to be `on_epoch_end`.

But in any case, what you are doing can be done via naive [modelcheckpoint callback](https://keras.io/callbacks/#modelcheckpoint). You don't need to write a custom one. You can use that as follows;

```
mc = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('weights{epoch:08d}.h5', 
                                     save_weights_only=True, period=5)
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, callbacks=[mc])
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, it works well :)    it's just what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You should implement on on_epoch_end rather implementing on_batch_end. And also passing model as argument for `__init__` is redundant.

```
from keras.callbacks import Callback
class WeightsSaver(Callback):
  def __init__(self, N):
    self.N = N
    self.epoch = 0

  def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
    if self.epoch % self.N == 0:
      name = 'weights%08d.h5' % self.epoch
      self.model.save_weights(name)
    self.epoch += 1
```