# Kernel crashes with Neural Network training loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm trying to create a Neural Network on a dataset that's huge. I tried training the neural network on the dataset as a whole and it resulted in a kernel crash.

To try to overcome that, i tried to save my model every 500 iterations, and load it again and pick where i stopped from, yet the kernel still crashes. I've added the code as well as the crash message. I'm really confused and don't know how to resolve this, any help would be appreciated.

-> Looping Code

```py
import joblib

for n in range(0,651191):
    if n %500 ==0:
        joblib.dump(model, 'my_NN_model.pkl')
        model = joblib.load('my_NN_model.pkl')

    model.fit(X_train.toarray(), y_train ,epochs=13, batch_size=500, verbose=1)
```

-> Error Message

```
Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done

The Kernel crashed while executing code in the the current cell or a previous cell. 
Please review the code in the cell(s) to identify a possible cause of the failure.
Click here for more info. View Jupyter log for further details.
```

Comment: You can save the model weights in each 500 epochs through checkpoints and call backs . Please reduce the batch size to 32/64 to avoid out of memory issue.             Attached relevant [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51186488/11530462) for reference.